# cmake cannot find libraries installed with vcpkg

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, xerces, vcpkg

I want to use `vcpkg` in a CMake project in Windows, because I need `boost` and `xerces` that are both handled by this package manager.

I've the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.12.0)

project (myproj)

set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${XERCES_ROOT})
set (Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set (Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
unset (Boost_INCLUDE_DIR CACHE)
unset (Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS CACHE)

# set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../cmake/modules)
find_package (Boost COMPONENTS filesystem regex REQUIRED)
find_package (XercesC CONFIG REQUIRED)

set (CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
message (STATUS "binary dir is ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
include_directories (${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/)
include_directories (${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..)
include_directories (${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories (${XercesC_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set (PROJECT_SRC
  code.cpp
  )

add_library (${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${PROJECT_SRC})
add_dependencies (${PROJECT_NAME} UPDATE_RESOURCES)
target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} XercesC::XercesC)
```

`Boost` and `xerces-c` are installed with `vcpkg`. Since I'm using Visual Studio Code I'm setting `vcpkg` variables in `settings.json`:

```
  "cmake.configureSettings": {
    "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE" : "some/path/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake",
    "VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET": "x64-windows"
  }
```

When I run che CMake I obtain following errors:

```
[cmake] CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2132 (message):
[cmake]   Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
[cmake]   directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
[cmake]   Boost's headers.
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   D:/projects/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:233 (_find_package)
[cmake]   src/myroject/CMakeLists.txt:24 (find_package)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at D:/Projects/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/xercesc/vcpkg-cmake-wrapper.cmake:1 (_find_package):
[cmake]   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "XercesC" with any
[cmake]   of the following names:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     XercesCConfig.cmake
[cmake]     xercesc-config.cmake
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Add the installation prefix of "XercesC" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
[cmake]   "XercesC_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
[cmake]   "XercesC" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
[cmake]   been installed.
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   D:/Projects/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:189 (include)
[cmake]   src/ZLA/CMakeLists.txt:25 (find_package)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
[cmake] See also "D:/Projects/zla/build/vscode/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
[cms-driver] Error during CMake configure: [cmake-server] Configuration failed.
```

At the moment I've installed `xerces` with vcpkg commands, while boost is currently not installed, but I was expecting that during the execution of the cmake command, `vcpkg` will download and build needed build packages.

I've tried also the command line:

```
 cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:/Projects/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows ../
```

but the result is the same.

What I'm doing wrong? How can I use vcpkg successfully?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> boost is currently not installed, but I was expecting that during the execution of the cmake command, vcpkg will download and build needed build packages.

This is not the case as far as I know. You need to install the packages you want with `vcpkg` beforehand for the triplet you plan to use (i.e. `x64-windows`). You will then need to ensure that the correct triplet is being used when you run CMake (check the `VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET` variable in your `CMakeCache.txt`). If it's incorrect, you can change it and re-configure using CMake.

Additionally, based on the error output you're getting, it doesn't seem that `xerces` has been installed properly either using `vcpkg`. You can check what is installed with `vcpkg` by running:

`vcpkg list --triplet x64-windows`

Comment: I've executed the command and xerces seems to be installed: `xerces-c:x64-windows                               3.2.2-8          Xerces-C++ is a XML parser, for parsing, generat…`. And in the `CMakeCache.txt` I've the correct triplet: `VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET:STRING=x64-windows`

Comment: @Jepessen ok, how about  boost?

Comment: I'm installing them right now with `vcpkg install boost:x64-windows`. It will take a while. But I think that the problem is with xerces, since it can be the same for all libraries.

Comment: For XercesC, remove `CONFIG` from your `find_package` call. CMake should be able to find the library if you have installed it with `vcpkg`.

Comment: I've removed `CONFIG`, even if it was suggested by xerces-c vcpkg package, but nothing changes.

Comment: Delete all XercesC variables in your CMake cache and re-configure?

Comment: @Jepessen I have the same issue with CMake error of your xerces lib. What was the solution? I've already checked the variable `VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET`. My CMake doesn't detect the lib. vcpkg list shows that the package is installed.

Answer (score 23):

1. You need to install the packages beforehand (using vcpkg install ).

   *(Then you could specify the toolchain as a CMake option:*

   ```
    -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\path\to\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake
   ```

   *but this won't work if you already specify a toolchain, such as when cross-compiling.)*
2. "include" it, instead, to avoid this problem:

   Add this line to the project CMakeLists.txt before find_package():

   ```
   include(/path/to/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)
   ```

Comment: Doing this sets the various `CMAKE_(SYSTEM_)?(PREFIX|LIBRARY|INCLUDE|FRAMEWORK)_PATH` cmake variables to enable the find_*() cmake functions to work, but note that these paths include the VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET.

Comment: Thank you so much! include("C:\\Users\\[...]\\vcpkg.cmake") solved the issue for me after hours of investigations. Thanks again!

Answer (score 21):

In theory it's as simple as (assuming vcpkg as installed in `C:/vcpkg` as it is for github actions);

1. Install your "foo" package with `vcpkg install foo`
2. Make sure your CMakeLists.txt finds and uses the package with;

   ```
   find_package(FOO)
   # Use these instead of the package doesn't have proper cmake 
   package support.
   # find_path(FOO_INCLUDE_DIRS foo.h)
   # find_library(FOO_LIBRARYS foo)
   include_directories(${FOO_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   target_link_libraries(myprogram ${FOO_LIBRARIES})
   ```
3. Run cmake with

   ```bash
   -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
   ```

But... this didn't work for me until I added `--triplet x64-windows` to the `vcpkg install` command.

The `DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` sets the various `CMAKE_(SYSTEM_)?(PREFIX|LIBRARY|INCLUDE|FRAMEWORK)_PATH` variables to enable the find_*() cmake functions to work, but note that these paths include the VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET. In my case the package install with `vcpkg install <foo>` defaulted to `x86-windows` but then invoking cmake with `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/....` defaulted to `x64-windows` so it couldn't find the the package.

Currently vcpkg defaults to the older x86 target, but modern Visual Studio (as used by githup actions) defaults to x64. The fix was to install the package with `vcpkg -triplet x64-windows install <foo>`. It took me way too long going down too many red-herring rabbit holes to discover this.

Comment: This is the solution for my problem. The only thing to mention is that it is `--triplet x64-windows`, not `--triple x64-windows`.

Comment: Thanks, i think I corrected this (or accepted a correction?) some time ago but forgot to acknowledge the correction.

Comment: According to vcpkg warning: the default triplet for vcpkg libraries *will* change from x86-windows to the detected host triplet since the September 2023 release. For anyone who doesn't want to wait, try to set the `VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET` environment variable.

Comment: You can also install a 64 bit packet with `vcpkg install foo:x64-windows`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and just solved it either with:

```
set(CURL_DIR "C:/Libs/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/curl")
```

or

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Libs/vcpkg/packages/curl_x64-windows/share/curl/")
```

I installed vcpkg under *C:/Libs*