# CMake not able to find magnum plug-ins installed with vcpkg

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, vcpkg

I've cloned and am trying to compile & run a c++ project from here: https://git.ist.ac.at/gsperl/MADYPG

I've installed all the dependencies as listed with vcpkg, but I am getting an error regarding the jpeg, and png importer magnum plug-ins, despite having installed them directly with vcpkg. Has anyone run into something similar before?

logs:

```
['-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake']
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "2.0")
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "2.0")
-- Found Corrade: C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include  found components: Main
-- Found Corrade: C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include  found components: Containers rc Utility PluginManager
-- Found Magnum: C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include  found components: Trade GL MeshTools Primitives SceneGraph Shaders Sdl2Application DebugTools AnyImageImporter
-- Found Corrade: C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include  found components: Containers rc Utility
-- Found Magnum: C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include  found components: GL Shaders
-- Found Corrade: C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include  found components: Containers rc Utility PluginManager
-- Found Magnum: C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include  found components: Trade
CMake Error at C:/Users/user/Desktop/cmake-3.23.0-rc2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find MagnumPlugins (missing: PngImporter JpegImporter)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/user/Desktop/cmake-3.23.0-rc2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/cmake/MagnumPlugins/FindMagnumPlugins.cmake:468 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/cmake/MagnumPlugins/MagnumPluginsConfig.cmake:26 (include)
  C:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:782 (_find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:104 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I've seen this similar thread as well [cmake cannot find libraries installed with vcpkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55496611/cmake-cannot-find-libraries-installed-with-vcpkg), but all other packages seem to be found by cmake without issue, so the solution required here is probably more specific. Any help very appreciated!

here's the cmakeLists.txt I'm using: https://git.ist.ac.at/gsperl/MADYPG/-/blob/master/src/CMakeLists.txt